# 500 Internal Server Error anchor error

Tags: apache, zend-framework, anchor, smarty3

I found this error in my Page

```
 Internal Server Error

 The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

 Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

 More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

And i found this error in my Apache Error Log

```
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:28 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:        C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to   increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/public/index.php, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /iBlog/index/login, referer: http://iblog.local/iBlog/
[Tue Mar 19 11:28:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
```

I want to access my other template

it's controller is index
and the template name is login

```
 <a href= "index/login">Login</a>
```

How can i solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

The page http://iblog.local/iBlog/ redirects to itself, and that sends the webserver into a loop.  You just need to make sure to remove that redirect.

Comment: Where do i find the redirect command @bchurchill ? i use bootstrap and application.ini ?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, I'm just looking at the log output.  Perhaps you can post your application.ini, .htaccess, and any other relevant config files?